# How to Angular 12 CkEditor 5 version 4 Add Custom Button

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

I want to add a special button to the toolbar in the 4th version of Ckeditor 5. I don't know how to do it. I looked through the documents but I couldn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own custom button you need to create a plugin that registers the button in the component factory and adds some actions that will be performed on the `buttonView:execute` event. You can follow the steps described in [creating a simple plugin guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/plugins/creating-simple-plugin-timestamp.html). A good and complementary reading about the UI library can be found [here](https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/ui-library.html).

After that, you need to customize `config.toolbar` which you can do it [here](https://github.com/barnatekse/ckeditor5-build-lateral/blob/4ae710265df432157f00c5912f51e1bc519cc6a8/src/ckeditor.js#L102-L119).